# restoring a saved canvas always fails and errors

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas paint app I'm working on that uses mouse clicks to draw. Simple enough. There's a listener on mouseup that saves the current drawing vis-a-vis getImageData and sets a session cookie that the user did in fact draw. Snippet:

```
var canvasData;
function save () {
  // get the data
  canvasData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

...

this.mouseup = function (ev) {
 if (tool.started) {
  tool.mousemove(ev);
  tool.started = false;
  save();
  document.cookie = 'redraw=true; path=/'
 }
};
```

The functionality I'm looking for is for the user to be able to leave the page, and come back to it, non-cached, and have the site see their cookie, read the drawing and map it using putImageData. Snippet:

```
function restore () {
  // restore the old canvas
  context.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
};

var checking = readCookie('redraw')
if (checking) {
  restore();
};
```

But when I try to do that, I get error consoles saying "Image corrupt or truncated" and "TypeError: Value not an object" on the putImageData line.

When I tried just saving the canvas to memory (save to data, draw image) :

```
var savedData = new Image();
function save () {
savedData.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
};
function restore () {
context.drawImage(savedData,0,0);
};
```

I got "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available" and "permission denied to access property 'toString'". Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'd put it on jsfiddle, but in this case that won't work so much, so [here's the full](http://mattriva.com/wip/working.html). Thanks.

Comment: Where do you save the canvas data to the cookie? According to the code in the question all you do is save the value `redraw=true`.

Comment: I'm not saving the canvas data to the cookie. The cookie is just to determine if the page will load canvas data. Canvas data is being saved as part of getImageData/putImageData and the var canvasData.

Comment: But where are you saving the `canvasData` variable? You do realize that the script state is wiped clean when the page is reloaded and all old variable values are lost?

Comment: I didn't. I was under the assumption that either of the methods were persistent. You're saying I should pass the canvasData var as the cookie and use that both as storage and to determine whether a user had been on the page?

Comment: If JS variables were persistent, there would be no need for cookies at all :) In any case, I suspect it's too much information to fit in a cookie; I'd look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) insted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are too limited in size so when you store data to them the data will be truncated it it exceeds the limit of about 4 kb - which isn't much when it comes to base64 encoded images (data url).

Modern clients (browsers) support more recent storing methods. You can use the following storage mechanisms in the major browsers (see link under each section for which browser support what):

### [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)

Stores data as a key/value pair. You can store the image as a Data Url or save arrays holding the data if that is more convenient.

This interface is synchronous.

(There is `localSession` as well which is for temporary storage).

Client-support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

For the usage you are describing this interface is probably the simplest (if you store often you will probably prefer an async interface), example:

```
localStorage[myKey] = 'myData';
var myData = localStorage[myKey];
```

### [indexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)

A little more complicated, but you can store data as [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects.

This interface is asynchronous.

Client-support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb

Example:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

### [file API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/)

Currently only supported in Chrome; works as a file-system with directories and so forth.  Here you store everything as blobs

This interface is asynchronous.

Client-support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem

Example:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

### [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Officially deprecated, but still in use (and will be for a while) with browsers such as Safari and IIRC Opera. Chrome has support as well, but not Firefox and IE.

This interface is asynchronous.

Client-support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=websql

Example:
http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

### [userData](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/domstorage2.shtml)

userData is supported in older IE versions. This API is somewhat limited though in more than one sense.

### [Cookies](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109)

Cookies are sent to server with each request so the bigger the cookie(s) the slower the communication. They are limited to 4 kb.

Be aware of that the client may or may not ask for user permission to store data in their computer for some of these interfaces - usually if you request more than 5 mb (Web SQL, indexedDB). This is up to the client though. This can seem intrusive to some users, so giving a heads-up to the user that the app will ask for this first can be a good idea.